# neo4j paging with lucene index OR how to skip index hits

Tags: lucene, indexing, iterator, neo4j, paging

I have a neo4j database (version 2.0.2) with 5M nodes and an index for all properties of those nodes.

When i have an index search result ([org.neo4j.graphdb.index.IndexHits](http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.2/org/neo4j/graphdb/index/IndexHits.html)) with 1M hits and only need result: 500k - 510k the iterator loads all nodes (0 - 500k) from the database and skips them which is pretty slow... Here's my current approach:

```java
final int pageSize = 5000;
final int page = 100;
final Index<Node> index = graphDatabaseService.index().forNodes("indexname");
final IndexHits<Node> hits = index.query(new WildcardQuery(new Term("property", "value*")));
final PagingIterator<Node> pagingIterator = new PagingIterator<Node>(hits.iterator(), pageSize);
pagingIterator.page(page);
final Iterable<Node> pagingIterable = new Iterable<Node>() {
    @Override
    public Iterator<Node> iterator() {
        return pagingIterator;
    }
};
for (final Node node : pagingIterable) {
    write(node);
}
```

is there a way how i can avoid the resource iterator from loading unnecessary nodes from the graph database?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use Cypher for this? You can use the SKIP and LIMIT keywords.

```
START n=node:indexname("property:value*")
RETURN n
SKIP 500000
LIMIT 10000
```

Don't know what the performance will be though.

Comment: Hi tstorms, thank you for answering! Yes I already saw that cypher has an "skip" command. Also cypher can parse my lucene query but I'm using a custom lucene QueryParser to provide numeric range queries for the appropriate fields.. If there is a way to make the ExecutionEngine use my custom QueryParser it would be a solution for me...